# pixelsearch in pyautoit library doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, autoit

I'm wondering why method `print(at.pixel_search(955, 1, 955, 1, 0x798795, 1))` giving me result with this data:`(355, 1)`. I'm trying to catch pixel colour in 955,1 coordinates and this line on the screen has pixels with same colour but in the left side, far away from my point. Could anyone guess, why this method searching pixel in the wrong coordinates?

Comment: [maybe?](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/MouseCoordMode). Why don't you use `PixelGetColor`?

Comment: Cause I need exact this function. I'm really currious about whay it happens that way?